# Transpose n*3 matrix to n*m matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a web server I am trying to generate a report giving the number of requests with various response codes within some fixed duration, say an hour.

From raw http access logs data I first generated an array of array, where each row has 3 cells: the hour, response code, and the number of requests. From that I then generate the final result. The logic is quite simple, for each row in input,

I have it working, see the small sample, but it does not seem "pythonic" I am wondering if there is a better way to do it. I have beginner skills in Python, and no exposure to various data processing libraries.

Is there a better way to do this? Are there any libraries that can be used to directly generate the final result from the initial raw data?

Also, I am pretty sure transpose is not the right name for this transformation, appreciate if someone can correct me on that as well.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

'''
data is an array of array n*3:
h  resp  count
1   200     15
1   201     23
2   200      9
2   201     75
2   404      5

result is an array of n*m:
   200  202   404
1   15   23     0
2    9   75     5
'''

def process(data):
  result = [[None]]
  for inrow in data:
    r,c,v = inrow[0], inrow[1], inrow[2]
    row = find_row(result, r)
    idx = find_column_index(result, c)
    row[idx] = v
  return result

def find_row(result, r):
  row = next((row for row in result[1:] if row[0] == r), None)
  if not row:
    row = [r]
    result.append(row)
    for x in result[0][1:]:
      row.append(0)
  return row

def find_column_index(result, c):
  columns = result[0]
  idx = next((idx for idx in range(len(columns)) if columns[idx] == c), None)
  if not idx:
    columns.append(c)
    for row in result[1:]:
      row.append(0)
    idx = len(columns) - 1
  return idx

def test():
  #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  arr = [
    [1, "200", 15],
    [1, "202", 23],
    [2, "200", 9],
    [2, "202", 75],
    [2, "404", 5]
    ]
  result = process(arr)
  print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  test()
```

Comment: Hello, I'm confused by your description of your input data and output: I am assuming your input and output data example is written incorrectly within your comments.

Did you want your output to be hours against type of request? i.e. ( hr 1 corresponding to 202 "200" responses, 23 "201" responses, and 0 "404" responses; hr 2 corresponding to 9 "200" responses, 75 "201" responses and so on?

Comment: @pooh17yes the first row has the last column incorrect in the comments, it is correct in the test data at the bottom. I will edit my post now. And you are correct about the output -- count of requests in each hour for various response codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can aolve that easily for you, just transfer dataframe to pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(arr = [
    [1, "200", 15],
    [1, "202", 23],
    [2, "200", 9],
    [2, "202", 75],
    [2, "404", 5]
    ],columns = ['h', 'resp', 'count'])
pivot = df.pivot(values='count',index='h',columns='resp')
print(pivot)
```

Comment: This is awesome. Is it also possible to generate the final result from raw data which is an array of `(timestamp, response-code)`? I would need to extract the hour (or compute some other period) and need to get a count of them

Comment: Finally managed to get `pandas` working on `cygwin`. There seems to be a small error above `df.pivot(values='count',index='h',columns='count')` should be `df.pivot(values='count',index='h',columns='resp')`. I'll wait for a day or two before editing your response. 

Also missing values show up as `NaN` which I would like to be `0`. I'll add another comment and edit once I figure out how to do that